# WCF Discovery Proxy asmx compatibility

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx

I developing some WCF web services which are supposed to be backward compatible with .NET 2.0. I want a WCF discovery proxy in front of my web services to redicrect the client to the correct service but my client is .NET 2.0 based. They will be accessing an old .asmx web service not a WCF service. Is that possible?